# Looking for a word (or set of words) to describe someone who moves their residence continuously over the years?

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, phrase-requests, idiom-requests, synonyms

For example, imagine a student who goes to an international university where he studies for 8 months and then comes back to his home country for 4 months. And he has to do this for 4 years, and then an additional 2 years in Grad school. Maybe he also studies in another country for one semester as an exchange student.
Therefore, every time he wishes to - let's say - buy something big (like a car or furniture or appliances), he says to himself something like:

> "I'm ___________ [only going to stay here for another few years]; there's no point
>   spending that much money".

Also, since he stays back in his home country for only 4 months every year, he does not really feel like it's his real home either.

Comment: The hypothetical student you mention seems to live a transient life.  Does this fit for you?

Comment: It depends a lot on how positively you want to spin it an how much you want to convey about personality on top of movement.  A "drifter" would convey a bit more aimlessness,  a "gypsy", a "leaf in the wind"/"rolling stone" convey "free spirit".  Wanderer, might emphasize curiosity.

Comment: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/peripatetic

Comment: Someone who moves *continuously* moves incrementally - no discontinuous jumps in location. Someone who moves *continually* moves many times.

Comment: what about "vagrant"?

Comment: Is the purposeful nature of his travel important to what you're trying to convey? Most of the words suggested so far, itinerant, nomadic, etc, connote lack of purpose to me. Also, if his movements are always between home and somewhere else he might be dual-homed or binational or something like that, even if the non-home location changes sometimes.

Comment: Give us a sample sentence please.  Peripatetic.  Divides his time between A and B.

Comment: @ToddWalton The nomadic lifestyle of e.g. Bedouins or Australian aboriginals doesn't lack purpose; they don't just wander around aimlessly; there's water, food, shelter and trade to be found in different places at different times.

Comment: Single-word-requests must have an example sentence. The reason for this is to let us know what sort of an answer you want: is it a noun you're looking for? A verb? An adjective? Voting to close until OP provides us the necessary info to allow good answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Peripatetic](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/peripatetic) is a word for someone always moving around, not living in one fixed place. "Perpetual tourist" is a phrase in use (see Wikipedia) for the class of wealthy peripatetic people avoiding becoming tax resident anywhere.

Comment: [Properly, though](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/141001), *peripatetic* in English doesn't deal with simply 'walking about' but with Aristotle's style of instruction. Teachers and some scholars can be paripatetic, but its extended senses as simply a synonym for *nomadic* are originally and largely ironic.

Answer (score 25):

As a noun, [**nomad**](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/127696).

As an adjective, [**nomadic**](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/127700).

That said, there are many synonyms or metaphors you could use: *unsettled*, *rootless*, *peripatetic*...

Comment: I wonder if peripatetic works best here, since the moves are for academic reasons.  The reference to Socrates will be lost on some, however.

Comment: @Palizsche If he were the *teacher* or *prof* moving about, absolutely 'peripatetic' is the best word. (In reference to the school of Aristotle, nothing to do with Socrates at all.) Not the case here, though, so using that word—at least to the people who grok it—would be taken as insulting.

Comment: @Ily, oops!  Thanks for the correction.  You are absolutely right that Aristotle was the official peripatetic one.  Socrates walked about a lot too.

Answer (score 15):

As both adjective and noun, [**itinerant**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/itinerant):

> Adjective: Travelling from place to place.
>
> Noun: A person who travels from place to place.

At the risk of offending the politically correct, I would also add [**gypsy**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/gypsy):

> A nomadic or free-spirited person. ‘why should she choose to wander
> the world with a penniless gypsy like me?’

Comment: There must be a German word for this. That's what the students did in Germany in the 19th century, but between German universities, isn't is?

Answer (score 0):

A frequently used idiomatic expression (often as an exaggeration) for this situation is: ***living out of a suitcase***.
See the example sentence below from ODO.

> "I'm ***living out of a suitcase***; there's no point
>   spending that much money (on a relatively immovable asset)".

ODO:

> **[live out of a suitcase](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/live_out_of_a_suitcase)**
>   *PHRASE*
>
> Live or stay somewhere on a temporary basis and with only a limited
>   selection of one's belongings.
>
> ‘Her parents told her she had to think about buying a home instead of
>   living out of a suitcase.’