# A single word for "moved around a lot"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a single word, probably a verb, to take the place of *moved around a lot.*

"I was in a military family. By the time I was nine, I lived in 6 different cities. We _________ [moved around a lot]."

It's okay if it's a verb-article-noun construction, but the verb should be clear that a lot of moving has been done.

And *travelled* doesn't quite cut it.

Comment: Very similar: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/383655/looking-for-a-word-or-set-of-words-to-describe-someone-who-moves-their-residen/383658

Comment: I wonder what’s wrong with “moved around a lot”  It seems like the best, clearest set of words to express the idea (and is likely what 99%,of the population would come up with) given that you’ve nixed *peripatetic* as too obscure.

Comment: Also very similar https://english.stackexchange.com/q/36190/17611

Comment: Almost a duplicate of :[What do you call a group of people that move a lot?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/29078/what-do-you-call-a-group-of-people-that-move-a-lot) wherein the answers are pretty much the same.

Comment: Why not use a phrase instead of s ingle word? 'Always on the move' seems to cut it. "I was in a military family. By the time I was nine, I lived in 6 different cities. We were always on the move, constantly uprooting and resettling in newer places.". Just a suggestion.

Comment: honestly, you would just say **"moved a lot"** there.  "moved around' is incorrect.  ("moved" or "moving" means "moved house, relocated cities, changed house"  the phrase "moved around" means like, at a ball game you got up and did a stretch, you walked around a room, etc.)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

How about "nomadic" or "nomads", as in "We were very nomadic" or "we were nomads."

**Nomadic**:

> ADJECTIVE
>
> Living the life of a nomad; wandering.

**Nomad**:

> NOUN
>
> 1 A member of a people that travels from place to place to find fresh
> pasture for its animals and has no permanent home.
>
> ‘the withering of their grasslands forced the nomads of the Sahara to
> descend into the Nile valley’

https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/nomadic
https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/nomad

Another option might be "transient" is the word you're looking for?  As in, "we were very transient."

**Transient**:

> NOUN
>
> 1  A person who is staying or working in a place for a short time only.

https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/transient

**Edit**: moved Nomad/Nomadic to the top; left Transient in so the comments still make sense.

Comment: I like *nomadic* as an adjective and *transiently* as an adverb. I'll see if I can make it work.

Comment: Of the current answers, I think *nomadic* is the best fit. It’s metaphorical—a military family isn’t *literally* a tribe of nomads—but it neatly conveys a sense of frequent moving and of not putting down roots.

Comment: *We were nomadic*, or some variant, suits my needs. Thank you

Comment: Downvoted because of just how bad of a suggest 'transient' is. 'Transient' makes it sound like the family phased in and out of existence in some kind of existential nightmare. It's a shame because 'Nomadic' is perfect.

Comment: Transient can also be used to refer to homelessness.

Comment: Can I suggest that you edit the answer so that "nomadic" is at the top? From the comments, that is the solution accepted by the OP, and I agree that it's much better than 'transient' (I'd even be tempted to remove 'transient' altogether).

Answer (score 30):

We were ***peripatetic***; [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/peripatetic):

> Travelling from place to place, in particular working or based in
>   various places for relatively short periods.
>
> ‘the peripatetic nature of military life’

Comment: Perfect fit but too advanced a word for my audience

Answer (score 10):

Relocated works well:

> "I was in a military family. By the time I was nine, I lived in 6
>   different cities. We relocated frequently."

***[Relocated](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/relocate)*** (Oxford)

> Move to a new place and establish one's home or business there.

There's an example of the word being used in the context you have mentioned on The U.S. Department of [Housing and Urban Development](https://www.huduser.gov/portal/periodicals/em/fall14/highlight1_sidebar.html) website:

> In 2012, there were over 1.2 million children in U.S. military
>   families, and more than three-fourths lived in households headed by
>   enlisted military service members. Military families with children
>   frequently relocate, often moving across state lines or to foreign
>   countries, and move every two to three years, on average.

Comment: Yes, *relocated* works well with an adverb like *frequently*.

Comment: or *were relocated frequently*, conveying the impression that you'd rather not have been, but had no choice. If that's what you want to convey, that is.

Answer (score 2):

Though not a verb, I would restructure the sentence to use something like "rootless" or "unrooted"/ "uprooted."

"A rootless, though relatively happy, stage of my life."

http://www.dictionary.com/browse/rootless

```
rootless
[root-lis, roo t-] 

adjective
1.
having no roots.
2.
having no basis of stability; unsteady:
a rootless feeling resulting from economic and social change.
3.
having no place or position in society; not in accord with the environment:
the homeless, rootless wanderer.
```

Comment: The OP has speciified a _verb_  which can take the place of "move around a lot".

Answer (score 2):

Migrated or Meandered

[Migrate](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/migrate)

> verb
>   1.1 (of a person) move to a new area or country in order to find work or better living conditions.

[Meander](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/meander)

> noun
>   1.1[in singular] An indirect or aimless journey.

Answer (score 0):

Itinerant is literally 100% the word you want.

As defined by [Oxford Dictionairies](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/itinerant):

> **itinerant**
> adjective.
>
> Travelling from place to place.
>
> noun.
>
> A person who travels from place to place.

Answer (score 0):

How about an "official" military term: PCSed.  PCS = Permanent Change of Station. You can always count on the military for a good acronym.

"I was in a military family. By the time I was nine, I lived in 6 different cities. We PCSed almost every year."

Comment: Another military oxymoron. I still remember being received once at a new TDY with: "Is this copy an original original, or only an original?"

Comment: Another military acronym. I can't keep up. SNAFU.

Answer (score -1):

"Displace" works well:

https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/displace

MEANING OF DISPLACE:
(VERB)
Take over the place, position, or role of.

Comment: Being displaced carries the side meaning of being unconsentingly forced to move instead of deciding to do so...

Answer (score -3):

*Wanderer* should be the ideal word.

Comment: @Glorfindel OP did say "probably a verb" indicating they would be open to suggestions if something interesting was presented.

Comment: Still, this is a substandard answer as it doesn't include an explanation why it's ideal (e.g. a dictionary reference).

Comment: There is no need for an explanation in a scenario. It does not entails any ambiguity or has an extended meaning. I think OP can manage that.